# Whats the better javascript grid web app, Dojo DataGrid, jQuery Grid or DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, datagrid, dojo

I'd like opinions from developers who have least tried two of the above. What did you like the most and the least? What was your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Jquery Datables. I can't really say it's better, but i tried others and this one was straight forward, flexible, and had good documentation. Also have not run into any bugs as i was with others.